# In Eclipse IDE how to disable the closing of an editor tab via plain right-click

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, tabs, ide, right-click

I am using Eclipse Oxygen (Ver 4.7.0) on CentOS with the UI shown via MobaXterm's X Windows server on Windows 7.

In Eclipse I have the weird problem that when I *right*-click on an editor tab the tab closes immediately! No context menu, nothing, just the tab vanishes. I would like to disable this, but I couldn't find any entry for right-clicking in the **Keys** section of the Preferences.

Is there another place where the right-click behaviour is set? Or how else can I disable this? The problem occurs only for editor tabs.

**Additional details:**

- The right-click behaves correctly *inside* an editor tab by bringing up the context menu. This shows that the right-click is not genearlly broken in the X Window system.
- The right-click behaves correctly in other X applications like PyCharm.

Comment: This isn't normal behaviour. Eclipse doesn't support configuring an action for right click at all, so I wonder if this is something else in your setup.

Comment: Does the current Eclipse behave the same way? You are using a pretty old Eclipse version.

Comment: @greg-449 It might be cause by some interference with the X Window server... I might have a look at MobaXTerm's documentation.

Comment: @howlger Will try out Eclipse 4.14 and report back.

Comment: @greg-449 Couldn't find anything in the MobaXTerm settings. Additionally the right click behaves correctly *inside* an editor tab by bringing up the context menu. (Added this info to the question.)

Comment: @howlger Having trouble installing 4.14.:-( Will stick to Oxygen.

Comment: Is this a retrocomputing thing? Otherwise, using such old software sounds like a waste of time. Do the people who use your software also refuse updates?

Comment: @howlger Unfortunately I have  not much control over the OS we are using. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An explanation**

A closer look revealed that Eclipse does show the context menu on *right-click **press-down***, but on *right-click **release-up*** it registers a *left-click* event.

Due to the particular situation of when the context menu was drawn, the mouse pointer than just always happens to sit over the top entry in the menu. And this top entry is `Close`. The following screenshot might illustrate this a bit (unfortunately without the mouse pointer):

[image]

**Solution**

The immediate solution for me is to move the mouse after pressing the right mouse button and  before releasing it.

Still I don't know *why* this happens only when right-clicking a tab and only for me - and probably not for many other people...